# Only Losers Read the News

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, computer-puzzle

Only Losers Read the News

[image: Only Losers Read the News]

<sub>Note the enigmatic tag. It's not meant to be clear what you're seeking.</sub>

Comment: This was a trap. I'm a loser now :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Partial:**

Upper line

> decodes through Morse code to:
>
>   **EASTGOESNOONTONINE**

Bottom line

> is written with small hex numbers and reads: 800100003AB812A013B012A012B80000F2578574B7569554F557000000008001
>
>  Looking these 256 bits as 16x16 1-bit bitmap:
>
> `#..............#
> ................
> ..###.#.#.###...
> ...#..#.#.#.....
> ...#..###.##....
> ...#..#.#.#.....
> ...#..#.#.###...
> ................
> ####..#..#.#.###
> #....#.#.###.#..
> #.##.###.#.#.##.
> #..#.#.#.#.#.#..
> ####.#.#.#.#.###
> ................
> ................
> #..............#`
>
>  i.e. **THE GAME**

Left line:

> Rotated clockwise can be interpreted like morse too (with one error though, that's why this may be not the right way):
>      ..... ...-- ..... .---- ..... ..... ....- .---- ..... ..--- ....- ..... ..... ...-- ..---
>      ----- ....- ---.. ....- .---- ..... -.... ....- ..... ..--- ----- ....- ..--- ....-
>      ----. ....- . ..--- ----- ....- .---- ..... ..--- ....- --... ..... ..... ....- .
>      .---. ....- . ....- --... ..--- . ..--- ----- ..... --... ....- ---.. ..... ----.
>
>  Decoded:
>  5351554152455320484156452042494E20415247554E#4E472E20574859
>  (# which is .---. is the error)
>  Translated from hex to ascii shows:
>      **SQUARES HAVE BIN ARGUN** - before #
>      **NG. WHY** - after #
>  or thanks to @f'' comment:
>
>  **SQUARES HAVE BIN ARGUING. WHY**

Right line:

> The string of digits (as [transcribed here](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/33398/15856) by @LeppyR64)
>  hes the following hex to ascii conversion:
>
>  **CHAR THE WE**

Comment: Upper line is a correct translation. Bottom line is an accurate transcription.

Comment: Master is on work computer so I can't double-check until Tuesday. However, the text is meant to read `ARGUING. WHY`

Comment: @EngineerToast If the dot at the end of the third line and the dot at the start of the fourth line are combined into a dash, then it reads `ARGUING` as intended.

Comment: Thanks for finding that, @f" I automated the process to make sure I didn't transpose anything but that's an issue I obviously overlooked.

Comment: So the intent was to read the top line, right line, left line, then bottom line. I think I was a little too subtle with "News" (north, east, west, south). If you go in that order, each line helps you read the next. Also, that means that the bottom line is the last line and finding `THE GAME` message is the end, thus making you think about [The Game](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Game_%28mind_game%29) and, consequently, lose The Game. You found the end but I didn't make it clear enough that you had...

Comment: @EngineerToast That's the reason to specify what the goal is supposed to be, so solvers know when they're done.

Comment: @f'' Yeah, lesson learned.

Answer (score 1):

Partial:

Right Line

> Looks like a histogram.  Read from top to bottom the values are:
>  4348415220544845205745

Comment: Right line is an accurate transcription.

Comment: Yeah, left is wrong, reworking it.